# How to make the end of the text in TextView transparent in Android

Tags: android, textview

I found an interesting design feature in the Google Play app.

[image]

As you can see at this picture text becomes invisible with some gradient. How can I do something similar in my app?

Comment: That’s not a transparent text, it’s just a gradient shape on top from white to 0 alpha. ;) Definitely a “visual trick” ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a color gradient like this

color_gradient.xml

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#ffffff"
        android:endColor="#00ffffff"
        android:angle="180"/>
</shape>
```

For example for the first row:

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World HelloWorld HelloWorld"
           android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World HelloWorld HelloWorld"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/gradient"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button_box"
        android:background="@drawable/color_gradient"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Tout mettre a jour"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#22bb66"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please note that there are several options for the layout. The central idea in this approach is to make the gradient drawable plus the white box containing the `Button` overlap the `TextView`s

Answer (score 1):

It could be probably be done by making `View` that overlaps `TextView` background transparent gradient, like so:

Create a `xml` in `drawable` folder with a name lets say "gradient":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:centerColor="#88FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:angle="90"
            android:dither="true"
         />
    </shape>
```

Additional Hex value before "FFFFFF" gives color an alpha parameter which could be considered as transparency or opacity. Now in `View` that overlaps layout write `android:background="@drawable/gradient"`I haven't tested it but it should work. And of course make sure to extend `View` that overlaps margin with `android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"`.

Answer (score 0):

An (more efficient) option would be to override `onDraw` and just draw a gradient on-top of your view:

```
   @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(),
                        Color.WHITE, Color.TRANSPARENT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    }
```

Note: If your View is a Layout, overwrite `dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)` instead.